# Mobile native keyboard autosuggest blocks loading of javascript autocomplete widget

Tags: javascript, android, firefox, mobile, autocomplete

The mobile device in question is any Android phone. I open firefox (btw, chrome doesn't cause this), go to a website like google search or IMDB and then type something in the search box. The native autocomplete activates above the keyboard as soon as I type the first letter. But I don't get the suggestions drop-down below the search box! It's only after I remove the native autosuggest (or autocomplete) that the javascript-enabled drop-down appears below the search.

In google search, however, the browser autosuggest works immediately and appears along with the native autosuggest:

[image: Google's autocomplete overcomes the native autocomplete]

But in IMDB (or others like Amazon), the browser autosuggest is delayed or blocked by the phone's autosuggest (and does not appear until the user selects the phone's suggestion or clears it):
[image: IMDB's autocomplete delayed by native autocomplete]

I think google is using "keydown" events to detect user typing but not sure how because it wasn't quite working after I tried writing a simple autocomplete myself locally. The "autocomplete=off" attribute (either on the form or the target input field) is also not helping.

How is it possible to not allow the native keyboard autosuggest delay or block the browser autosuggest?

Answer (score 0):

Use the input event to detect the change.

If you are using jQuery/zepto do this.

```
$(selector).bind('input', function(){
   //autocomplete logic
});
```

In native js

```
document.getElementById(selector).addEventListener('input', function(){
    //autocomplete logic
});
```